# ie8 margin top bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, margins

I have no idea why IE8 is doing this, but I have two divs that contain navigation.  One is floated left, the other is floated right.  Both divs have a margin-top of 10px on them.  Everything looks great in all the other browsers except IE8.  The top margin disappears.

I've tried changing the doctype from HTML5, to transitional, to strict and no suck luck.

I've ran a combo of changing the doctype and using the `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"` meta tag as well as `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=1"` and `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,chrome=1"` and it still no change.

I've added a &nsbp; and a `height:0;` to the `clear:both;` div in the CSS as indicated here:
[IE8 - Container with margin-top: 10px has no margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245914/ie8-container-with-margin-top-10px-has-no-margin)

And that doesn't seem to work either.  So, I am stumped.  Not too sure what else to try.

One thing I forgot to mention is that cufon is applied to the text, so I am not sure if that could be causing any issues or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a reset stylesheet:
[CSS Reset](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/)

Comment: Already have that within wordpress. but now that you mention it, I wonder if that could be causing some issues?  I'll try commenting it out from the header file and see what happens